# How to pass parameter in birt and display them in report using scripted dataset?

Tags: struts2, birt

How will i be able to

1. set parameters from java class
2. access it from Birt report

please elaborate i am new to this.

Answer (score 1):

Use IRunAndRenderTask class in your java program to add parameters.
eg:

```
IRunAndRenderTask  task = engine.createRunAndRenderTask(design);
          // pass necessary parameters
          task.setParameterValue("ordParam", (new Integer(10101))); //static parameter 
          task.setParameterValue("value", Integer.parseInt(value)); // pass dynamic parameter
          task.validateParameters();
```

Also add a new parameter in Data Explorer Report parameter with name same as that you have given in your program. like here "value".

And Atlast,Drag your parameter in your report Design. and its done.

Comment: Thank you Reetika, I have one more doubt, how can i print excel report by setting output format in java file?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome user.
To print Birt Report in Excel format Use EXCELRenderOption class.

```
EXCELRenderOption xlsOptions = new EXCELRenderOption(options); 
                  xlsOptions.setOutputFormat("xls");
                  response.setHeader(   "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+downloadFileName);
                  xlsOptions.setImageHandler(new HTMLServerImageHandler());
                  xlsOptions.setOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
                  //xlsOptions.setOption(IRenderOption.EMITTER_ID,"org.uguess.birt.report.engine.emitter.xls");
                  xlsOptions.setOption(IRenderOption.EMITTER_ID, "org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.prototype.excel");
                  iRenderTask.setRenderOption(xlsOptions);
```